# How do I denote the Cartesian square of the set of all functions from $X \to Y$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation, cardinals

It is my understanding that to denote, say, the set of all integer sequences (set of all functions from $\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{Z}$) we write:

$$\mathbb{Z}^\mathbb{N}\equiv\{f\mid f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{Z}\}$$

What if I want to denote the set of all ordered pairs with elements from $\mathbb{Z}^\mathbb{N}$? That is how do I denote the Cartesian square of $\mathbb{Z}^\mathbb{N}$? Is it this:

$$\left(\mathbb{Z}^\mathbb{N}\right)^2$$

or can I write it like this: $\mathbb{Z}^\mathbb{2N}$? maybe this: $\mathbb{Z}^\mathbb{N\times2}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Cartesian square" is nothing more than the Cartesian product of a set with itself.

$$\left(\mathbb Z^\mathbb{N}\right)^2$$

is okay, but doesn't look nice.

$$\mathbb Z^\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb Z^\mathbb{N}$$

will be understood by everyone.

The other versions can be misinterpreted for something else completely, don't use them. You are not working with powers of real numbers, don't forget that.

Comment: Say I wanted to denote an $n$-ary Cartesian product of this set. Would $\left(\mathbb{Z}^\mathbb{N}\right)^n$ be the best way to do this?

Comment: @OzanerHansha It would be one way. You can always define something to fit your needs, e.g. say $\mathcal Z:=\mathbb Z^\mathbb N$, then $\mathcal Z^n$ looks nicer. Yet I don't know if there is a canonical alternative for $\left(\mathbb Z^\mathbb N\right)^n$